# How can I combine # or ## with an enumeration in xaringan and rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

```
---
class: left

# Relative Werte

--
##1. Bessere Vergleichbarkeit der Stimmen aller Kandidaten pro Stimmbezirk

--

##1. Bessere Vergleichbarkeit der Stimmen eines Kandidaten über alle Stimmbezirke
```

The problem: If I write 1. 1. instead of "-" then I won't see "1...., 2....". The automatic enumeration (same as the \dot if I write "-") are somehow overwritten by the "##" sign. How can I prevent xaringa to overwrite the meaning of "-" in my case? When I define, e.g. .large[...], then the enumeration is also overwritten and I just see "1..... 1." or "- .... - ...." instead of the enumeration or dots.

Thank you for your help!

Best regards
Markus

Comment: can you show what the error looks like? This might be minor but can you put a space between `##1.` like this `## 1.`

Comment: You can't combine a header + a list in markdown (so not xaringan issue but just simply how markdown works).

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine a header + a list in markdown but if what you want to do is to make your list item bigger then you can do something like below

````
class: list-bigger

```{css, echo = FALSE}
.list-bigger ul li {
  font-size: 2em!important;
}

.list-bigger ol li {
  font-size: 2em!important;
}
```


# Header

--

1. Ordered List 1
--

1. Ordered List 2
````

You can move everything in the css chunk to the an external css file if you like here. 
Essentially I'm defining a class called `list-bigger` and the slide with ordered and unordered list with that class will make the font size to `2em` (change this number to what suits you).